# Date input doesn't change value on user input

Tags: javascript, date

I have a user input type=date, when the user enters the date and click on the add button it is supposed to take that input value to calculate the days until the selected date. Right now it always uses the preset value in the html input tag not the user input.

Repo: https://github.com/tbd007/Travel-Planner-APP
Live: ud-travelapp.com

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```js
let tripdate= document.getElementById('start').value;

function getMyDateValue(e) {
    // Get the date value from the srcElement of the event
   var tripdate = e.srcElement.value;
   console.log(tripdate);
   return tripdate;
}

  // Add an event listener to my date field 
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("blur", getMyDateValue);


let d= Date.parse(tripdate);
const e= d+86400000;
const f = new Date(e);
const g = f.toLocaleDateString();
let end_date= g.split(".").reverse().join("-");
let h = end_date.substring(5,9);
let k = tripdate.substring(5,10)
console.log(tripdate)
console.log(h)
console.log(k)

function getDiff(){
var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();

    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) 
    {
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 

    if(mm<10) 
    {
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    //start_date = today;
    
    var diff =  Math.floor(
        (
            Date.parse(
                tripdate.replace(/-/g,'\/')
        ) - Date.parse(
                today.replace(/-/g,'\/')
        )               
        ) / 86400000);
    return diff;
 };

let days=getDiff();
console.log(days);

function addTrip(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML+=`<p>${tripdate} : Departure in ${days} days!</p>`;
    document.getElementById('location').innerHTML=`<p>${city}</p>`;   
 }
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Travel App</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../dist/main.css">
</head>
 <body>
<div id = "app">
  <div class ="headline">
    <h1>TRAVEL PLANNER</h1>
  </div>

  <div class ="wrapper">
    
    <form class="" onsubmit="Client.handleSubmit(event)">
    <label for="city">Enter City here</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" placeholder=" Enter Location">
    <input type="text" id="countryCode" placeholder=" Enter Country Code">
    <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2020-05-20">
    <input id="addbtn" type="submit" value="SAVE TRIP" onclick="addTrip(event)" >
</form>
  </div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="output">
    <div id="mainpic"></div>  
      <h3 id="tripdet">TRIP DETAILS</h3>
      <div id="details">
      <div id = "showlocation"></div> 
      <div id = "showdate"></div>
      <div id = "weatherdata"></div>
  </div>
</div>

  

  <div class ="holder">
    <div class = "title"><h2>My Trips</h2></div>
   <div id = "entryHolder">
    <div id = "location"></div> 
   <div id = "date"></div>
   <div id = "content"></div>
   <div>
```

Comment: boil it down to an example you can post the source code of here and show what you're having trouble getting to work. Pointing to github project isn't helpful to others in the future since the project can change or disappear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions seeking debugging help should include a minimal example of code that displays the issue on stackoverflow, along with expected and actual results with any error messages.

Comment: I added the code snippet

Comment: Can you try and use momentjs.. That will take away half of pain to calculate the days or months etc

Comment: I did try moments the problem is it didnt work the handleSubmit() function did not take over the value.